# temporarily redirect while waiting for SSL to be issued?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I just inherited a new site but messed up the SSL cert by losing the private key.

The url would have been https for anyone using the site meaning right now they are clicking on a broken site, or an SSL error to be more clear.

Is there any way around this for now, ideally just a redirect to a holding page would suit me fine.

I cant redirect to http using htaccess as I think htaccess doesnt even get a chance to kick in at that stage

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: What you want is not possible.

Details: HTTPS is HTTP inside a SSL tunnel. The redirect is done with HTTP. Since you messed up the establishment of the SSL tunnel it will not be able to start with HTTP (inside the non-existing tunnel) and thus cannot do a redirect.